# How to find a basis for the Kernel of the following transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I want to find a basis for all $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$ which satisfies:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\-2 & -3 & -4\\3 & 4 & 5\\-2 & -3 & -4 \end{bmatrix}M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

The way that I know is to rewrite the linear transformation as $T : \mathbb{R}^{9} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{12}$ and then, try to find the Kernel. But it's too massive! Is there any simpler solution?

Bests,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a matrix product $AB=C$, the $i$th column of $C$ is equal to $A$ multiplied by the $i$th column of $B$.

As each column in the right-hand side is zero, each column of $M$ must be in the kernel of the leftmost matrix.

Comment: Thank you all...

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of the "leftmost" matrix obviously is generated by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr -2 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
So each column of $M$ must be a scalar multiple of it.

Comment: Very beautiful. tanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of the linear map$$(x,y,z)\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\-2&-3&-4\\3&4&5\\-2&-3&-4\end{bmatrix}.(x,y,z)$$is$$\bigl\{(t,-2t,t)\mid t\in\mathbb R\bigr\}.$$So, the space for which you want to find a basis is$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}t_1&t_2&t_3\\-2t_1&-2t_2&-2t_3\\t_1&t_2&t_3\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,t_1,t_2,t_3\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. i can take it